# How to convert byte array YUY2 format to BitmapSource

Tags: c#, rgba

I have an image byte array (named colorByteArray in the code), YUY2 format, and I try to transfer it to JPEG encoding.

Until now, I'm working with byte array RGBA format and here his code:

```
        BitmapSource bitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(
            width,
            height,
            96,
            96,
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32,
            null,
            colorByteArray,
            MainWindow.COLOR_BYTE_PER_PIXEL * width);

        //JPEG encoder
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.QualityLevel = MainWindow.JPEG_QUALITY;
        // create frame from the writable bitmap and add to encoder
        BitmapFrame bmf = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource);
        double scaleRatio = Math.Sqrt(MainWindow.COLOR_SCALING);
        ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        TransformedBitmap scaledBmf = new TransformedBitmap(bmf, scale);
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(scaledBmf));

        MemoryStream msColor = new MemoryStream();
        encoder.Save(msColor)
```

How can I convert the code to work with YUY?
I didn't found way to crate the BitmapSource.

Appreciate any advice

Answer (score 1):

Save your self some pain and use the ImageMagik toolkit for .NET rather than raw GDI code, it handles all that kind of stuff for you, I recently wrote an article on it which you can find here:

http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/manipulating-images-with-imagemagik.html

ImageMagik as a toolkit has been around for years and there's nothing it can't do where Images are concerned.

For some time you did have to use the C# process assemblies, and call the command tools directly, but since you can now just use NuGet to pull in pre made binary libraries and start to code against them, you get all that power in a small set of DLL's

The code plex page for the project I show in my blog post has lot's of easy to understand examples, covering all aspects of the kit, and anything not covered can be picked up from the intellisense in Visual Studio.